Create settings for the application using viewmodel and data class
I want to add application settings to a separate screen and save them in the most convenient and simple way possible.This will be a drop-down list of keywords that can be added or removed with the click of a button.
class SettingsActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val gameViewModel: GameViewModel = viewModel()
            val gameUiState by gameViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

            val langs = gameUiState.allkeyWords

            Column {
                for (lang in langs) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(10.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp))
                        Text(text = lang, fontSize = 18.sp, modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                    }
                }
                Row {
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            gameViewModel.oneywordsallChange("test word")
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("add word", color = Color.Green)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

My viemodel class:
class GameViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(GameUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<GameUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    var allkeyWords: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()


    fun oneywordsallChange(newValue: String) {
        allkeyWords.add(newValue)
    }

    fun getoneywordsallChange(): (MutableSet<String>) {
        return allkeyWords
    }
}

My data class:
data class GameUiState(
    var allkeyWords: Set<String> = setOf("animal", "auto", "anecdote", "alphabet"),
)

After pressing the button, the list is not updated on the screen.

There is something wrong with your code and its formatting, probably a copy&paste error. Can you fix that?

Can you explain the exact problem?
Your code snippet isn't particularly workable. It could be that you haven't included your UI inside a setContent block in onCreate or you're not observing your state.
But... giving you the benefit of the doubt, I suspect your UI isn't updating. That's because you're not updating your state. You can update the list all you want, but if the state isn't changing, the view won't change. And with collections, you can't just modify them because only the content changes and not the reference. If the reference doesn't change, it also won't trigger a UI update.

Darryl Johnson
,Yes, after pressing the button, the list is not updated on the screen.

@BenjyTec already correctly identified the problem, but I would suggest another solution:
Instead of having two independent variables in your view model that hold the same information I would advise you to get rid of one alltogether, namely allkeyWords. When you remove that, oneywordsallChange would look like this:
fun oneywordsallChange(newValue: String) {
    _uiState.update { it.copy(allkeyWords = it.allkeyWords + newValue) }
}

The function getoneywordsallChange should also be removed without replacement since the data is already available in uiState.
Updating your view model like this enforces that there is only a Single Source of Truth regarding the set of keywords. This way you cannot accidentally update the value at one place but not update it at another anymore.

It seems like you never actually publish the allkeyWords Set to the _uiState MutableStateFlow. Please try to update your oneywordsallChange function as follows:
fun oneywordsallChange(newValue: String) {
    allkeyWords.add(newValue)
    _uiState.value = GameUiState(allkeyWords.toSet())  // publish updated Set
}

Also note that with your current code, you will have an empty Set in your allkeyWords variable, but the _uiState will emit a Set containing "animal", "auto", "anecdote", "alphabet". You should initialize both to the same Set, otherwise you will get inconsistent data. You can either do
data class GameUiState(
    var allkeyWords: Set = setOf()
)

or
var allkeyWords : MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf("animal", "auto", "anecdote", "alphabet")

